# Flex box items, shrink to fit text wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using a flex box for my navigation bar, it works fine however when the text inside the `li` items drops onto a new line, I'd like it if the actual width of the `li` element would shrink. For example like this:

**Normal Width:**
[image: Normal Width]

**Shrunk:**
[image: Shrunk]

[image]

The wasted space to the left and right of the 'Dance & Performance' text means the items overlap and look awful.

How can I get the `li` to have an auto width?

```css
header {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #58595B;
  z-index: 100;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 95%;
}
ul.header_items {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.header_items li {
  background-color: #7E489C;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 18px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.4s;
  padding: 2px;
  width: auto;
}
.header_items li a {
  font-family: 'Norwester-Regular', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<header id="static_nav">
<ul class="header_items" style="padding-left:0px;">
    <li id="header_item_first"><a href="home" id="index_button">Home</a></li>
    <li id="header_dp"><a href="dance-performance" id="dance_button">Dance &amp; Performance</a></li>
    <li id="header_af"><a href="adult-fitness.php">Adult &amp; Fitness</a></li>
    <li id="header_w"><a href="https://www.millyacademy.com/workshops.php">Workshops</a></li>
    <li id="header_cc"><a href="https://www.millyacademy.com/corporate-celebrations.php">Corporate &amp; Celebrations</a></li>
    <li id="header_g"><a href="https://www.millyacademy.com/showcase.php">Gallery</a></li>
    <li id="header_s"><a href="https://www.millyacademy.com/shop.php">Shop</a></li>
    <li id="header_c"><a href="https://www.millyacademy.com/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li id="button_student_login"><a href="student-login" id="login_button">Student Login</a></li>
</ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML as well as the CSS to allow us to reproduce the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: you want your site output as you shown in first image or shown in second image?

Comment: My tests seem to indicate that this isn't possible.

Comment: I'll add a third image now.

Comment: In any case, please fix your invalid html first `</li></a>`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the HTML. I've moved your code into a Stack Snippet to make it easier for us to replicate the issue. There are a couple of instances where your `a` and `li` tags are closed the wrong way round i.e. `</li></a>`. You may want to correct these. :)

Comment: If you think about it logically...this is the correct behavior given the nature of flexbox. You want the list items to be as flexible but when text breaks there is extra room to allocate so it does...where there is room available, Perhaps flexbox is not what you need here or perhaps another approach. At the moment i don't think this is possible (with flexbox) )but I'd be interested in being proved wrong.

Comment: Updated the HTML code to correct the tags. My bad!

Comment: can you please post image of your desired output. it will help us to get that.

Comment: The third image is how I want it to look, just without the padding (black boxes highlight said padding). I'll mock something up in Illustrator to better explain it.

Comment: I think what i'll have to do is use @media in my CSS to change the flex box width etc at certain intervals, been thinking about how it could work and i've realised it wouldn't work.

Comment: I always use display:table/table-row/table-cell constructs when I need something to collapse as you want it. Slightly better backwards support. Although flex-boxes in this case 'should' work just as well, they appear to calculate differently from table-cells.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `.header_items` from `justify-content: space-around;` to `justify-content: space-between;` and `.header_items li` from `padding: 2px;` to `padding: 2px 0.5em;` - Changing the horizontal padding may get you closer to what it is you are seeking.